# Failed to fetch 'us.archive.ubuntu' when sudo apt-get update, cannot connect to network

Tags: networking, server, updates, virtualbox

Ok, so I'm running Ubuntu server 14.01 LTS in virtualbox, and I'm trying to sudo apt-get update, but I get an error saying that it failed to fetch us.archive.ubuntu.com and security.ubuntu.com . I figured they might be down or something, and waited over 24 hours. Still failed. Then, I tried to ping 8.8.8.8 and it says `connect: Network is unreachable` . I tried changing network adapters in vbox from host-only to bridged, and vice versa. Nothing. Help?

edit: My network connection is just fine outside of my vm on the host system.

Answer (score 0):

"host only" means just that; the VM can only talk to the host, nothing beyond that. So that's expected.

When you say you switched to bridged mode, did you actually restart the VM? If not, it would still have the old, host-only address, and of course it wouldn't be able to talk to the outside world, as it wouldn't be getting an address from your router (an improper use of the term, but we're stuck with it).

Either bridged mode or NAT-ed mode should work, no reason why it shouldn't,

Comment: Yes. I switched to bridged and restarted. I can now ping 8,8.8.8 and get a response with 74% packet loss. I retried updating but didn't work the first time. Second time, it decided to work, took over 13 mins though. Updating took kinda a while too. But thanks!